# Multiple boxplot in a single Graphic in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I'm a beginner in Python.

In my internship project I am trying to plot bloxplots from data contained in a csv

I need to plot bloxplots for each of the 4 (four) variables showed above (AAG, DENS, SRG e RCG). Since each variable presents values ​​in the range from [001] to [100], there will be 100 boxplots for each variable, which need to be plotted in a single graph as shown in the image.

This is the graph I need to plot, but for each variable there will be 100 bloxplots as each one has 100 columns of values:

[image: Graph]

The x-axis is the "Year", which ranges from 2025 to 2030, so I need a graph like the one shown in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hBYZ.png) for each year and the y-axis is the sets of values ​​for each variable.

Using `Pandas-melt` function and `seaborn` library I was able to plot only the boxplots of a column. But that's not what I need:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
 
df = pd.read_csv("2DBM_50x50_Central_Aug21_Sim.cliped.csv")
mdf= df.melt(id_vars=['Year'], value_vars='AAG[001]')
print(mdf)
ax=sns.boxplot(x='Year', y='value',width = 0.2, data=mdf)
```

Result of the code above:

[image: Result]

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: How does it work to have separate boxplots for 100 columns, and also set `Year` as the x-axis? Each of your columns spans from 2025 to 2030.

Comment: [This plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0hZM.png) is what you get from the first 24 columns of each variable. In this figure, the left-most boxplot of the `AAG` variable is for `TB_acc_AAG[00001]`, the second one is for `TB_acc_AAG[00002]` and so on. But the x-axis is not actually `Year` since there are only six values to that.

Comment: In the original file, all 100 columns of data for each of the variables have values for each year (from 2025 to 3030), that is, when filtering the column "Period" by the year 2025, I will have a filtered dataset referring to the year 2025 and the same for the other years.

Comment: Each dataset filtered by year will be used to make one graph like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0hZM.png) [each graph will have 5 different plots, one plot for each variable (AAG, DENS, SRG, RCG and Thick) with their respective 100 boxplots, since there are 100 columns for each variable]. The plot's x-axis is the Year (year that was filtered) and the y-axis the data referring to this year. Therefore, as a result I need 6 graphs (one for each year).

Comment: Thank you for responding!

Comment: Following the removal of the image URLs, the text "This is the graph I need to plot, but for each variable there will be 100 bloxplots as each one has 100 columns of values" now is a broken link. Moreover, if these images were required in order to get an answer, it is best not to remove it now that you have an answer. Other readers may still wish to add a new answer.

Comment: As per the other question, I have decided to restore the images here, since their removal effectively acts as a vandalisation of content. Once you get an answer, it is best to leave a question as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives you five subplots, where each subplot only contains the data of one variable. Then a boxplot is generated for each year. To change the range of columns used for each variable, change the upper limit in `var_range = range(1, 101)`, and to see the outliers change `showfliers` to `True`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("2DBM_50x50_Central_Aug21_Sim.cliped.csv")

variables = ["AAG", "DENS", "SRG", "RCG", "Thick"]
period = range(2025, 2031)
var_range = range(1, 101)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
flattened_axes = fig.axes
flattened_axes[-1].set_visible(False)

for i, var in enumerate(variables):
    var_columns = [f"TB_acc_{var}[{j:05}]" for j in var_range]
    data = df.melt(id_vars=["Period"], value_vars=var_columns, value_name=var)
    ax = flattened_axes[i]
    sns.boxplot(x="Period", y=var, width=0.2, data=data, ax=ax, showfliers=False)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the graph I showed, it was just an example of what I would like the graphs to look like. The graphs you plotted are great, but when I try to insert the 100 boxplots into the plots, it doesn't fit, even if I change the size of the boxplots. So I would like to know if there is any way to do this, by changing the arrangement of the plots (not plotting side by side) maybe it would be possible to increase the plot area, so that the boxplots fit right.

Comment: How about [stacking them vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euC10.png) or even forcing them to [share the same x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag4B9.png)?

Comment: I think both works well, but I need to give a thought on which use. Would it be possible to share the code that allows doing each one?

Comment: Also, do you know if there is any tool that allows to edit the graphics so that they have the formatting of the graphic I sent as an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hBYZ.png). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited my answer and added the layout functions to the code. Both Matplotlib and Seaborn allow you to [change the style and appearance of the plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html).

Comment: It was definitely a great help. I am so thankful for it :)

Comment: I am sorry, but there was a mistake in my interpretation of the problem.
It is not to make the boxplot of each of the hundred columns referred to each variable as I explained before.
The correct thing is to have only one boxplot for each different variable, that is, for each year there will be 5 boxplots (because there are 5 variavies), with each boxplot made from the 100 columns of data of each variable. In this way, it will be possible to adjust the plots of all six years in a single graph. Could you please help me with the changes in the code?

Comment: Edited my answer to incorporate this change. It was needed to aggregate variable columns into a single column for each variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I messed up again, but I promise this will be the last. The correct thing would be to plot all the bloxplots of a variable (one for each year) in just one graph, that is, there will be 5 graphs (one for each **Variable**) and each graph will contain 6 boxplots (one for each **Year** ). So the x-axis will have the years information and the y-axis will be the boxplot made from the junction of the 100 columns of the variable. Sorry for bothering you again, but could you help me with this?

Comment: This is basically what you have done in the question yourself. You just have to create a subplot for each variable. I edited my answer.

Comment: I really appreciated your help. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have another data-frame with the same variables and amount of data as the previous one, but the years vary from 2030 to 2037. Therefore, my task is to add to the [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUsII.png) the boxplots referring to the years 2030 to 2037 for each variable. For that I tried to join the data-frames in a single one through the Pandas `.concat`, but I think because the files have the same variables and number of columns, Pandas `.melt` is not selecting all the data-frame. Could you help me to find a way to solve it?

Comment: This is a different issue, and I think you better open a new question for it. This page has become crowded and overwhelming for other people to follow.

Comment: @halfer thank you for your advice. I will ensure I will improve in the issues you pointed out. I truly appreciated it.

Comment: Thanks @RODRIGO :=)